# Can we add Lagrangian-like multipliers for a joint constraint $g(x, y)=0$ in a min-max problem?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Assume we have a problem

$$ \min_x \max_y f(x, y) \ \ \text{ s.t. } \ g(x, y) = 0$$

I wonder if it is possible to incorporate this constraint into an objective in Lagrangian-like fashion:

$$ \min_{x} \max_{y, \lambda} \min_{\eta} f(x, y) + \eta \cdot \lambda \cdot g(x,y) $$

but my attempts at getting such an expression failed so far. For example, if we consider $h(x,y,\lambda) = \min_{\eta} f(x, y) + \eta\lambda g(x,y)$, it already takes the $-\infty$ for all values of $(x, y, \lambda)$ such that $g(x, y) \neq 0$ including $\lambda = \pm \infty $, so there is no reason for $\min_x$ not to choose an $x$ s.t. $g(x,y)\neq0$.

It is no suprrise since I was trying to get some characteristic term $ f(x, y) + \chi(g)(x, y)$ that would be "not favorable" to nor minimization or maximization, so it should not be one of $\pm \infty$.

If constraints are not joint, i.e. $g(x)=0$ and $k(y)=0$ then adding two multiplier terms seems to work $p(x,y,\lambda,\eta) = \max_\eta \min_\lambda f(x, y) + \eta \cdot g(x) + \lambda \cdot k(y)$ is equal to $+\infty$ if $k(y) \neq 0$ and $-\infty$ if $g(x)\neq 0$ and $\infty$ if both do not hold (which is weird, but reasonable). But this is not the case I am interested in.

Comment: What is meant by $\min_x \max_y f(x,y) \: \mbox{such that } g(x,y)=0$ ?  This does not seem to be a well posed problem. It may be impossible to satisfy the constraint without jointly choosing $x,y$, so they cannot be chosen separately.

Comment: @Michael but if it was a min-min problem, it would have been well posed, right? Would it help if $g(x, \cdot ) = 0 $ was satisfiable for each $x$? But I am still not sure why would a constrain like $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$ be fine for an optimization problem and bad for a minimax problem - for any $x < 1$ it reduces the choice of $max_y$ to to two options $\pm (1-x^2)$. So the objective turns into normal optimization $\min_x max\{ f(x, (1-x^2)), f(x, - (1-x^2))\} $. But I made up this case, maybe if constrains on $y$ depend on $x$ there's no way of solving the problem? I must be missing something

Answer (score 0):

When solving this kind of problem

$$
 \min_x \max_y f(x, y) \ \ \text{ s.t. } \ g(x, y) = 0
$$

we are searching for the $f_g(x,y)$ saddle points and those points are handled normally in the Lagrange Multipliers procedures so

$$
L(x,y,\mu) = f(x,y)+\mu g(x,y)
$$

and the stationary points are determined by

$$
\nabla L = 0
$$

regarding only saddle points.

Comment: Makes sense if one considers that FOC for a problem like this would be $\nabla f(x,y) = \mu \nabla g(x,y)$, $g(x,y) = 0$ - i.e. that we are looking for a point such that we can't improve without violating $g$ (in our case gradient components should be multiplied by (1, -1) to encode min-max)). I wanted to use this to dualize the whole function wrt $x$ because it is concave wrt it. In optimization I would just do that because all constraints are embedded into the objective via these Lagrangian terms.